# Get URL of merged css file in Meteor

Tags: css, meteor, tinymce, stylesheet

Meteor merges all (s)css files together as part of the build process and generates a single css file called /merged-stylesheets.css?biglongnumber

I'm using TinyMCE in a Meteor app and I want the content within the TinyMCE window to use the same css as the page it's on. TinyMCE has the ability to do this:

```
tinyMCE.init({
    content_css : '/myStyles.css' 
});
```

So I want to get the path to that merged stylesheet so I can pass it to TinyMCE. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Any reason using /merged-stylesheets doesn't work by itself?  The stuff after the ? shouldn't matter...

Comment: My understanding is the text after the ? is used to version / timestamp the CSS file, so if it is not provided then the browser may use the wrong version of the file.

Comment: Gotcha...how about just adding a Math.random()*100000 to the end?

Comment: `+ new Date()` could be better - it's kind of *browser cache buster*.

Comment: These suggestions would work but they are not optimal because they would result in the browser unnecessarily downloading the CSS file multiple times. What I really want is to find out the actual URL of the file.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the URL of the CSS files on the current page using the browser DOM, then make a comma-separated list of them and give it to TinyMCE. The following gets only the CSS files matching the current domain (& port and scheme):

```
//Get CSS files being used
var schemeDomainPort = location.protocol+'//'+location.hostname+(location.port ? ':'+location.port: '');
var cssFiles = '';
for (var i = 0; i < document.styleSheets.length; i++) {
    if (document.styleSheets[i].href && document.styleSheets[i].href.indexOf(schemeDomainPort) === 0) {
        cssFiles += cssFiles ? ',' + document.styleSheets[i].href : document.styleSheets[i].href;
    }
}

//Configure TinyMCE
$scope.tinymceOptions = {
    content_css: cssFiles, 
    ...
}
```